# how do I populate sencha xtemplates form json object, (MVC approach)

Tags: json, sencha-touch

I'm new to sencha and I'm trying to populate some templates as following:

Model:

```
Ext.define("GS.model.Oferta", {
        extend : 'Ext.data.Model',
        config : {
            fields : [{
                        name : "type",
                        type : "string"
                    }, {
                        name : "logo",
                        type : "string"
                    }, {
                        name : "description",
                        type : "string"
                    }, {
                        name : "product",
                        type : "string"
                    }]
        }
    });
```

Store:

```
Ext.define("GS.store.BoxStore", {
        extend : 'Ext.data.Store',

    config: {
        storeId: 'boxStore',
        model : 'GS.model.Oferta',
        proxy : {
            type : 'ajax',
            url : 'TestData.json',
                reader: {
                    type:'json',
                    rootProperty: 'dataArr'
                }
        },
        autoLoad : true
    }
    });
```

Xtemplate:

```
Ext.define("GS.view.Box", {
        extend : 'Ext.Panel',
        requires : ['Ext.form.FieldSet'],
        layout : {
            type : 'absolute'
        },

        config : {
            tpl : Ext.XTemplate.from('tp1'),
            data:{}
        }

    });
```

Controller:

```
Ext.define('GS.controller.Main', {
 extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
store: 'boxStore',

config : {
    stores: ['BoxStore'],
    models: ['Oferta'],

    refs : {????
    ????????    },
    control : {
??????????
        }
    }
},

    getData: function(list, index, element, record){
    this.getBox().push({
        xtype: 'panel',
        data :[record.get('type'), record.get('logo'), record.get('logo'),     record.get('product')],
        scrollable: true,
        styleHtmlContent: true
    });
},
//called when the Application is launched, remove if not needed
launch: function(app) {

}
});
```

HTML:

```
            <textarea id='tp1' class="tp1">
           <div class="product_small">
             <div class="type" id"type">

             </div>
             <div class="logo"><img src="resources/images/garbarino_logo.png" />
             </div>
             <div class="small_description">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
             </div>
             <div class="product">
                 <span style="color:rgb(0,193,209); font:bold 35px/40px Tahoma,Verdana;">1.700</span><span style="color:rgb(0,193,209); font:bold 13px/20px Tahoma,Verdana;"> puntos</span>
             </div>
            </div>
        </textarea>
```

How do I manage to populate the templates? Should I attempt to create a box in the controller and set it there?

Thank you very much
Ignacio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to update the data of a tpl directly use the method setData, otherwise you might want to try using Ext.DataView instead of Ext.Panel and linking the dataview to the store directly. It's hard to tell what exactly is needed - your example code shows you pushing a new panel to getBox (presumably the component that has the template) but you are trying to set the data on that new panel, which does not have a template.

Comment: It's like this: each list item contains 7 Json Items (7 Boxes) with a static layout, for which I use panel with several items containin Boxes (forget about blog and push), so the question would be how do I manage to pass the boxes to its respective position without having to hardcode it's position (panel.getItems().get(0).add(box)).Thank you very much

Comment: Please look at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13633271/how-to-manage-custom-layouts-in-sencha-touch-2