# how to manage custom layouts in sencha touch 2

Tags: sencha-touch

Hi I'm working on the following panel:

```
Ext.define("GS.view.BoxesPanel", {
extend : 'Ext.dataview.component.DataItem',
xtype : 'boxesPanel',
alias : "widget.boxespanel",

config : {
    xtype : 'panel',
    layout : 'vbox',
    width : '60%',
    align : 'center',

    items : [{
        xtype : 'panel',
        flex : 2,
        layout : 'hbox',
        height : '70%',
        margin: '10 10 10 10',
        items : [{
            xtype : 'panel',
            flex : 1,
            items : []
        }, {
            xtype : 'panel',
            flex : 1,
            layout : 'vbox',
            items : []
        }, {
            xtype : 'panel',
            flex : 1,
            layout : 'vbox',
            items : []
        }]
    }, {
        xtype : 'panel',
        layout : 'hbox',
        flex : 1,
        height : '30%',
        margin: '10 10 10 10',
        items : [{
            xtype : 'panel',
            flex : 2,
            items : []
        }, {
            xtype : 'panel',
            flex : 1,
            items : []
        }]
    }]
}
});
```

Here is how I'm currently accessing the panels (in my controller)... :

```
 launch : function(app) {
    var store = Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('boxStore');
    var boxesPanelList = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('BoxesPanelList')[0];
    var boxesPanel = Ext.create("GS.view.BoxesPanel");

    store.onAfter('load', function() {// Boxes are loaded when the store finishes  loading it's data, if not, the boxes appear empty
        Ext.each(store.getData().items, function(item, index) {// Iterates through BoxStore data objects (JSON)
            var box = Ext.create("GS.view.Box");
            box.setData({
                type : item.data.type,
                description : item.data.description,
                product : item.data.product
            });
            switch(item.data.position) {
                case "1":
                    box.setCls("product_vert");
                    boxesPanel.getItems().get(0).getItems().get(0).add(box);
                    break;
                case "2":
                    box.setCls("product_small");
                    boxesPanel.getItems().get(0).getItems().get(1).add(box);
                    break;
                case "3":
                    box.setCls("product_small");
                    boxesPanel.getItems().get(0).getItems().get(1).add(box);
                    break;
                case "4":
                    box.setCls("product_small");
                    boxesPanel.getItems().get(0).getItems().get(2).add(box);
                    break;
                case "5":
                    box.setCls("product_small");
                    boxesPanel.getItems().get(0).getItems().get(2).add(box);
                    break;
                case "6":
                    box.setCls("product_horiz");
                    boxesPanel.getItems().get(1).getItems().get(0).add(box);
                    break;
                case "7":
                    box.setCls("product_small");
                    boxesPanel.getItems().get(1).getItems().get(1).add(box);
                    boxesPanelList.add(boxesPanel);
                    boxesPanel = Ext.create("GS.view.BoxesPanel");
                    break;
            }
        });
    }, this);
}
});
```

Thank you very much for any information you provide.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more precisely what you're trying to achieve here ?

Comment: Im looking for  way to "push" data into a the panels (panelOne, panlTwo)

Comment: You should use the MVC pattern. http://www.sencha.com/blog/architecting-your-app-with-sencha-touch-2-mvc This means creating your views and then associating data to these view in your controller upon some events.

Comment: It's like this: each list item contains 7 Json Items (7 Boxes) with a static layout, for which I use panel with several items containin Boxes (forget about blog and push), so the question would be how do I manage to pass the boxes to its respective position without having to hardcode it's position (panel.getItems().get(0).add(box)).Thank you very much

Comment: What is the difference between case 2 and 3?

Comment: case 2 and 3 go in the same panel as case 4 and 5, its a 2 x 2 "grid" where box 1 is double height (default width) and takes position 0, boxes 2, 3, 4 ,5 (default height & width) take 1 and box 6 (double width, default height) takes position 2, and box 7 takes position 3 (default hight and widht)

Comment: So what exactly are you trying to accomplish? Will the box data change and you need to automatically map them to the correct positions? If so you would still need to specify the order. I would recommend you decide on a code for each size combination, which looks like the cls you are already setting. Set that on each container, and then on each box load find the first available matching container. The order data comes in would then decide the order of the boxes.

Comment: how can I finde the fisrt available matching container?

Comment: Did you resolved your problem?

Comment: No I have not, have you?